# Error in MySQL sub query when adding "GROUP BY"

Tags: mysql, group-by, subquery, mariadb

I'm using MariaDB, and my subquery below returns results but if I add a the final line, being "GROUP BY linked_item" it returns the error "check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version."

Unsure why using GROUP BY is an error.  I need to output one totalsum per unique linked_item from the subquery result - any way to achieve this outcome would be fine.

This code returns the correct two column subquery result

```
SELECT linked_item, totalsum 
FROM 
(SELECT a.linked_item, a.total_actual_cost as totalsum FROM pl_detail a
WHERE a.total_actual_cost IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT b.linked_item, (b.number_units*b.cost_per_unit) as totalsum 
FROM pl_detail b 
WHERE b.total_actual_cost IS NULL) t
```

error when adding this line:

```
GROUP BY linked_item
```

Comment: Group By is for use with aggregate functions - you don't have any.

Comment: Cheers, just google'd aggregate functions & to fix I've changed the first line to "select linked_item, sum(totalsum)" & included the GROUP BY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use SUM (or another aggregate function) in your SELECT

```
SELECT linked_item, SUM(totalsum) as TotalSum
FROM 
(SELECT a.linked_item, a.total_actual_cost as totalsum FROM pl_detail a
WHERE a.total_actual_cost IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT b.linked_item, (b.number_units*b.cost_per_unit) as totalsum 
FROM pl_detail b 
WHERE b.total_actual_cost IS NULL) t
GROUP BY linked_item
```

All columns need to be either an aggregate function OR in the GROUP BY clause

Answer (score 0):

This is a minimized and faster query for your expected result by avoiding sub-queries. Here 3 queries are reduced to 1 query.

```
SELECT 
  a.linked_item,
  SUM(
    CASE
      WHEN a.total_actual_cost IS NOT NULL 
      THEN a.total_actual_cost 
      WHEN a.total_actual_cost IS NULL 
      THEN (a.number_units * a.cost_per_unit) 
    END
  ) AS totalsum 
FROM
  pl_detail a 
GROUP BY a.linked_item
```